# Python: preferred way to allow child class to override parent method return types?

Tags: python, inheritance

Let's say I have two classes:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        data = 0

    def copy(self):
        other = A()
        other.data = self.data
        return other 

class B(A):
    # B *does not* override A's __new__ or __init__
    @classmethod
    def from_A(cls, a):
        a.__class__ = cls
        return a

a = A()
b = B()

B.from_A(a)  # instance of B
b.copy()     # instance of A
B.from_A(b.copy() # ...    B
```

The problem of course is that `B().copy()` returns an instance of `A`. I can circumvent this by either defining a wrapper `copy` method for `B`, or I can call `B.from_A(B().copy())`. The former option requires wrapping all such methods; the latter feels dangerous and introduces a lot of boilerplate.

Is there a more standard Pythonic way of doing this? I'm asking in particular for the case in which I do not have access to `A`'s implementation, and the relevant methods are not classmethods. For a concrete example: I could be trying to subclass `pandas.DataFrame` and want to ensure that `B.copy()` and `B.merge(...)` return instances of `B`, not `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of this usually has to be done in `A.copy()` -- it has to be designed so that it allows subclassing and will return the appropriate subclass

Don't call `A()` explicitly in the `copy()` method, call the class constructor for the object.

```
def copy(self):
    other = type(self)()
    other.data = self.data
    return other
```

Note that this won't work if a subclass adds additional parameters in its `__init__` method.

Comment: Are you referring to `A.copy` here? Question says "I'm asking in particular for the case in which I do not have access to A's implementation"

Comment: I didn't notice that part of the question.

Comment: Thanks, I see your subsequent edit. So if `A` is not designed to allow subclassing in this way, are you pretty much out of luck, or are there any other reasonable options?

Comment: You could try using `copy.deepcopy()`, but I don't think there's a really general solution, because the nature of copying is often class-specific.

Comment: I'm using copy as an example in the OP, but I'm interested in handling several methods, all of which return a new instance of `A`. I'll clarify this

Comment: My point is that there really is no general purpose solution. Classes vary in their needs too much. The base class needs to define how this is intended to work, you can't force it to obey by new rules.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will lessen the boiler plate:

```py
class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def from_A(cls, a):
        a.__class__ = cls
        return a
    
    def wrap_method(self, method):
            out = getattr(self.__class__,method)(self)
            out.__class__ = self.__class__
            return out
```

Then you will have to call `b.wrap_method('copy')` instead of `B.from_A(b.copy())` and they both outputs the instance of B:

```py
B.from_A(b.copy()), b.wrap_method('copy')
>>> (<__main__.B at 0x7fb2915c20f0>, <__main__.B at 0x7fb2915c2400>)
```